# Selecting Distinct Values with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I am attempting to insert entries to a table based on the DISTINCT values of one table, which also don't contain values from a seperate table. I am assuming the problem is in my JOIN.

In the table wp_posts the values for ID are unique, but in the table wp_term_relationships the object_id can have multiple entries.

What I want is to get all the distinct ID that contain certain words in the description (in wp_posts) but also do not have certain term_taxonomy_id from the wp_term_relationships tables associated with their object_id in that table

Thanks for the responses, I made some changes, and am still running into issues.

```sql
//Here is what I have so far:
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, '5209', '0' FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Cadillac%'
AND wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Escalade%'
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id not like '5209';
```

The resulting query attempts to insert values that do not meet the last condition. I am assuming the problem is with the join.

Edit after Answer:

Thanks to Gen Wan for suggesting the code that lead me to my answer!
Here is the correct code that worked:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, '5209', '0' FROM wp_posts 
JOIN (
    select object_id, term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships
    WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 5209
)a
ON wp_posts.ID = a.object_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Cadillac%'
AND wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Escalade%'
AND a.term_taxonomy_id not like '5209';
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Why not just have the last line say, `AND  wp_term_relationships.wp_term_relationships <> '5209'`

Comment: wp_term_relationships  is a string?? or number if string then not like if number then <>

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, I was just about to ask that... :-)

Comment: since you gave ' ' i assume it tibe a string

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the column is wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id not  wp_term_relationships.wp_term_relationships

Comment: wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id is an integer. I tried removing the ' ', but still get the same result. The query still Selects values with wp_term_relationships.object_id that already have an entry with wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 5209

Comment: @NicholasPavlinsky, could you accept one of the answers by clicking that little green check at the left side of each solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to get the distinct object_id and term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships firstly:

```
select distinct object_id, term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships
```

Then join the derived table with your conditions:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, '5209', '0' FROM wp_posts 
JOIN (select distinct object_id, term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships)a
ON wp_posts.ID = a.object_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Cadillac%'
AND wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Escalade%'
AND a.term_taxonomy_id not like '5209';
```

Comment: This got me where I needed to be. There are multiple entries for each object_id in wp_term_relationships (1 for each term_taxonomy_id) so I had to get rid of the values I didnt need to check for in order for the join to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, '5209', '0' FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Cadillac%'
AND wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Escalade%'
AND  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id not like  '5209';
```

Comment: Resulting query still tries to insert values that already have the term_taxonomy_id 5209

Comment: @NicholasPavlinsky since you have edited your question check now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database server you are working on but try changing you last conditions from:

```
AND NOT wp_term_relationships.wp_term_relationships = '5209';
```

to:

```
AND wp_term_relationships.wp_term_relationships <> '5209';
```

Comment: I tried that originally, and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You hardcoded the taxonomy id = 5209 in your select. That is why your insert will put 5209 in all of the inserted rows.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ID, **'5209'**, '0'
```

Please show us sample data so that we can clearly see the issue.
I went to this free site to create a database sandbox: https://www.db-fiddle.com/
Then I run your query and I don't see a problem on the result.
If you have a different expected result then please show it to us.

Thanks.

site: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ 
copy and paste this and execute:

Schema:

```
create table wp_posts(ID integer, post_content varchar);
insert into wp_posts values (1,   'Cadillac Escalade');
insert into wp_posts values (2,   'Ford Escape');
insert into wp_posts values (3,   'Cadillac Escalade');
insert into wp_posts values (4,   'Escalade Cadillac');
insert into wp_posts values (5,   'Escalade Cadillac');
create table wp_term_relationships(object_id integer, term_taxonomy_id integer); 
insert into wp_term_relationships values (1            ,5209);
insert into wp_term_relationships values (1            ,1000);
insert into wp_term_relationships values (2            ,5209);
insert into wp_term_relationships values (2            ,1000 );
insert into wp_term_relationships values (2            ,5209);
insert into wp_term_relationships values (3            ,1000);
insert into wp_term_relationships values (5            ,5209);
insert into wp_term_relationships values (5            ,1000);
```

QUery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, term_taxonomy_id, '5209' as new_term_taxonomy_id, '0' as nothing_ 
FROM wp_posts 
JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Cadillac%'
AND wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Escalade%'
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id <> 5209;
```